# Data disappears after a split second using JS to render form data on same page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was trying to render form data on the same page using JavaScript.

**JavaScript**

```
function renderInput(age) {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += age;
}
```

It works when the submit button is placed outside the form element.

**HTML - When it works**

```
<form>
  <label><b>Enter your age</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="age" id="user_input">
</form>

<input type="submit" 
onclick='renderInput(document.getElementById("user_input").value);'><br/>

<div id='display'>Your age is </div>
```

While it renders the the div with the id "display" just for a split second and then disappears if the submit field is placed inside the form element.

**HTML - When it doesn't work**

```
<form>
  <label><b>Enter your age</b></label>
  <input type="text" name="age" id="user_input">
  <input type="submit" 
onclick='renderInput(document.getElementById("user_input").value);'><br/>
</form>

<div id='display'>Your age is </div>
```

I can't seem to get my head around this. Why is this happening?

Comment: when you submit a form, the browser "loads" the form "action" url - as your form has no "action" then the browser reloads the current page - which is what is happening

Comment: Thanks! I was wrongly assuming of the form to be doing nothing if I don't have an action field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stop the form from submitting, by returning `false` with the `onclick` event like this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick='renderInput(document.getElementById("user_input").value); return false;'>
```

Comment: It would be better to put the listener on the form since it can be submitted without clicking the button.

Comment: I was going with the question, otherwise listening to form submit is the best.